# Show all links you have recently/ever upvoted on Hacker News

Tags: hacker-news

How can you show all links you have recently/ever upvoted on [Hacker News](http://news.ycombinator.com)?

Is there a page somewhere that shows all this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is indeed an answer to this mysterium (searched the whole net, but found it finaly by myself).

Click on your user-id and then on saved stories.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to get a similar list, but for comments instead. Any clues?

Comment: How about clicking on your loginname, and then on comments further down, above the update button?